# Does setting icon badge number locally require user permission in iOS?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

My app sets the application icon badge number locally. It reflects the number of rows in a table view.

Do I need to ask the user for permission to do it?

Do I need to register the app to appear in the notification center? By no means do I use push notifications.

If I'm just setting the icon badge number and not using UILocalNotifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can increase it anytime you want. This is not push notification feature so does not require user permissions.

Answer (score 2):

**No,** You can use it anywhere.This is  not  only in case push notification, somebody use it for chat count also. So there is `no need to get user permission`. And also, `No need` to register to `notification center` if not use UILocalNotifications.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any user authorization to use :

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:1];
```

Also, the `UILocalNotification` class has a property called `applicationIconBadgeNumber` that will let you set the icon badge number when you send local notifications.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS10+, you need to do this before you can setApplicationIconBadgeNumber

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in }
```